# PostgresSQL replace variance of value into 1 standard value

Tags: postgresql

I have column that contain of multiple value, for example Master of Science, Master of Art,etc
How to replace all of these value into Master degree. then count of the value that have Master degree.

Comment: Please add sample data, the expected output and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query for replace

```
select case when columnName like UPPER('%master%' ) then 'Master degree' end master_degree
from tableName
```

You can try below query for count

```
select count(*) as total_degree
from tableName
where columnName like UPPER('%master%' )
```